# How to debug pressing 'o' freezes Vim

Tags: vim

My Vim normally works fine, however, at times, it gets into a weird state.

When it does, pressing <kbd>o</kbd> in normal mode causes Vim to hang. I can then get it out of that state by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. I'd expect the cursor to move down one line and enter `insert` mode.

What's interesting is that I can replicate it every time once it gets into this state. Pressing <kbd>o</kbd> again will hang again, until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

It is hard to debug whether it is a specific plugin since it doesn't happen every time. If I disabled one plugin, I wouldn't know for sure it was the plugin that was causing this problem since Vim usually works, so it occurs maybe once every few days.

Also, I don't have any mapping to <kbd>o</kbd>. `map o` returns `No mapping found`.

I am not sure how to debug this; does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which terminal and os are you using?

Comment: Does the issue occur when you press 'o' or 'shift+o' i.e. 'O' ?

Answer (score 2):

Since I could replicate this issue when I got into this weird state, I could profile the problem.

```
profile start freezing_debug.txt
profile func * 
profile file *
```

I managed to find that `GetLastRealCodeLNum` in Vim package was the root cause. Searching Google helped me find that a [ticket](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4562) had been created and all I probably have to do is update my Vim version to pull this change in.

Comment: Select this as the solution when Stack Overflow times out; That way the question will be marked as answered.